# How to copy matrix to column array

Tags: scala, csv

I'm trying to copy a column of a matrix into an array, also I want to make this matrix public.

Heres my code:

```
val years = Array.ofDim[String](1000, 1)
val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("Top_1_000_Songs_To_Hear_Before_You_Die.csv")
val i=0;
//println("THEME, TITLE, ARTIST, YEAR, SPOTIFY_URL")   
for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
  val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
  years(i)=cols(3)(i)
}
```

I want the `cols` to be a global matrix and copy the column 3 to `years`, because of the method of that I get cols I dont know how to define it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're **three different problems** in your attempt:

1. Your regexp will fail for this dataset. I suggest you change it to:

   `val regex = ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))"`

This will capture the **blocks wrapped in double quotes** but containing commas (courtesy of Luke Sheppard on [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/38q9c))

2. This `val i=0;` is **not very scala-ish / functional**. We can replace it by a `zipWithIndex` in the for comprehension:

   `for ((line, count) <- bufferedSource.getLines.zipWithIndex)`
3. You can create the "global matrix" by extracting elements from each line (`val Array (...)`) and returning them as the value of the for-comprehension block (`yield`):

It looks like that:

```
for ((line, count) <- bufferedSource.getLines.zipWithIndex) yield {
  val Array(theme,title,artist,year,spotify_url) = line....
  ...
  (theme,title,artist,year,spotify_url)
}
```

And here is the complete solution:

```
val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("/tmp/Top_1_000_Songs_To_Hear_Before_You_Die.csv")
val years = Array.ofDim[String](1000, 1)

val regex = ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))"

val iteratorMatrix = for ((line, count) <- bufferedSource.getLines.zipWithIndex) yield {
  val Array(theme,title,artist,year,spotify_url) = line.split(regex, -1).map(_.trim)
  years(count) = Array(year)
  (theme,title,artist,year,spotify_url)
}

// will actually consume the iterator and fill in globalMatrix AND years
val globalMatrix = iteratorMatrix.toList
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will get the `col` column from the CSV. There is no error handling here for any empty row or other conditions. This is a proof of concept so add your own error handling as you see fit.

```
val years = (fileName: String, col: Int) => scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName)
    .getLines()
    .map(_.split(",")(col).trim())
```

Here's a suggestion if you are looking to keep the contents of the file in a map. Again there's no error handling just proof of concept.

```
val yearColumn = 3

val fileName = "Top_1_000_Songs_To_Hear_Before_You_Die.csv"

def lines(file: String) = scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines()

val mapRow = (row: String) => row.split(",").zipWithIndex.foldLeft(Map[Int, String]()){
  case (acc, (v, idx)) => acc.updated(idx,v.trim())}

def mapColumns = (values: Iterator[String]) =>
  values.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(Map[Int, Map[Int, String]]()){
    case (acc, (v, idx)) => acc.updated(idx, mapRow(v))}

val parser = lines _  andThen mapColumns

val matrix = parser(fileName)

val years = matrix.flatMap(_.swap._1.get(yearColumn))
```

This will build a `Map[Int,Map[Int, String]]` which you can use elsewhere. The first index of the map is the row number and the index of the inner map is the column number. `years` is an `Iterable[String]` that contains the year values.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding contents to a collection at the same time as it is created, in contrast to *allocate* space first and then update it; for instance like this,

```
val rawSongsInfo = io.Source.fromFile("Top_Songs.csv").getLines

val cols = for (rsi <- rawSongsInfo) yield rsi.split(",").map(_.trim)
val years = cols.map(_(3))
```